# Unity 3D vertical scrolling background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, background, vertical-scrolling

Is there any option how to use 2D background in unity 3D with scrolling?
For the games like Helix jump etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it very simple. Your image should be great enough, to be scrollable. The offset is a useful base to realize. If you set offset and decrement it scrolls down, incrementing scrolls up. You just need the y-axis to adress correctly.

Comment: Hello thanks for answer. https://imgur.com/a/KV378Jf Can u show me some example of the code please?

Comment: Thisone should work for you. https://answers.unity.com/questions/717249/vertically-scrolling-2d-background-clips.html

Comment: https://rakeshmalikblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/unity-scrolling-background/

Comment: i will try it but i think that second one will not work for me :/

Comment: The way of Rakesh is the better one. There are also some manuals on youtube. I think, that the variables should be proofed, to make it suitable. Maybe, that your variables have different names. My 4.x sources runs on 5.x too. Just failed declarations can do kidding your mind.

Comment: I one time made this but at 2D game now i am doing 3D and i have some rotation at camera so watched that screen.

Comment: At the camera i am having Rotation x 17

Comment: I got one scrolling script that works for me. But now i will need little help. https://imgur.com/a/2S3oFIv Here i sending screnes i am using weather seasons for background if u see but i need to somehow get by actual active season background to scrolling script

Comment: I cant read these images. Did you placed the functioncall before or behind the update / renderscene? Is your skymap set to transparency?